# Como indexar páginas de um sistema no Google? (SEO)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, arquitetura-de-software, seo

Eu tenho uma dúvida, que não consegui encontrar resposta em lugar nenhum, as que eu encontrei me deixou um tanto quanto confuso.

Como fazer para indexar as urls do meu sistema em ASP.NET no google, por exemplo um site estático já tem as páginas .html criadas, já no caso de um wordpress você seleciona a URL amigável e o google consegue identificar a URL, e se na url conter a palavra "/carro" o google consegue enxergar. Agora se eu for fazer um sistema em ASP.NET, as rotas são criadas automáticamente, conforme o usuário vai navegando, ou seja não existe nenhum arquivo onde tenha esse conteúdo.

Agora no caso de um determinado modelo de carro um exemplo "fiat ducato" eu teria que passar na URL do sistema via GET, só para o google indexar? mas como o google vai saber que existe uma URL que tem esse nome sendo que será criado apenas quando passar o parametro?

Eu estou bem perdido nessa questão e estou para fazer um sistema que precisa ter o SEO otimizado.

Comment: Gabriel o Google clica! Sim o bot do Google vai "clicar" em tudo do site, vai escanear tudo, entrar em todos os link, e o Google não faz indexação só pela URL, ele tb lê o conteúdo da página, alt de imgs, H1, H2, Meta tags, etc, então não se preocupe exclusivamente com a URL, o Google tem outros meios para reconhecer o conteúdo da página

Comment: @hugocsl obrigado pela resposta, mas no caso desses sistemas como Wordpress como funciona essas urls?

Comment: E outra pergunta... o conteudo desses H1, H2 e alt de imagens serão gerados automaticamente, por exemplo tenho uma lista de imóveis que será renderizado o HTML apenas se o usuário for no filtro inicial e selecionar tipo casa, e clicar no botão de pesquisa.. isso o google faz também?

Comment: O Google lê o que vc entrega na requisição, ele vlai acessar um link, o que vc devolver é o que ele contabiliza. Tratamento de URL amigável é outra coisa, é indicado sim para o SEO e para a Usabilidade, mas não é um fator que funciona insoladamente para o seu rankeamento

Comment: É só criar um sitemap, lá você informa todas as URLs que existem na sua aplicação.